# Use methods as callback in C++ in a convenient way

Tags: c++, c++11, methods, callback

I want to use methods as callbacks. I know that there is a very generic syntax that allows to use any kind of callable as a callback:

```
void f(int x) { cout << "f("<<x<<")" << endl; }

class C
{
public:
   void m(int x) { cout << "C::m("<<x<<")" << endl; }
};

class C2
{
public:
   void registerCallback(function<void(int)> f)
   {
      v.push_back(f);
   }

private:
   vector<function<void(int)>> v;

   void callThem()
   {
      for (int i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
      {
         v[i](i);
      }
   }
};

int main()
{
   C2 registrar;

   C c;
   registrar.registerCallback(&f); // Static function
   registrar.registerCallback(bind(&C::m, &c, placeholders::_1)); // Method

   getline(cin, string());

   return 0;
}
```

Please note that it must be possible to register methods of any kind of class as callbacks.

However I would like to allow the following more convenient syntax for registering methods:

```
registrar.registerCallback(&C::m, c); // Method
```

Is it possible to provide a `registerCallback()` overload that allows a more basic syntax without the need for using `bind` when registering a method?

Comment: Did you try making an overload of `registerCallback` that's a template that passes the result of a call to `std::bind` to the current implementation of `registerCallback`?

Comment: No. I will try it. So there is no sensible way to implement this without bind?

Comment: Based on what you're trying to accomplish `std::bind` seems to be the most sensible way to construct the function object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that syntax I think you can easily wrap it in an overload:

```
   template <typename Func, typename Obj>
   void registerCallback(Func f, Obj& obj)
   {
      registerCallback(bind(func, &obj, placeholders::_1));
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just against `bind` you could also use a lambda:

```
registrar.registerCallback([&c](int x){c.m(x);});
```

Note: Be careful with this, I'm using a reference to `c` here if that has a shorter lifetime than `registrar` you will segfault if you try to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

You want an overload for a class method:

```
template <typename Class>
void registerCallback(void (Class::*method)(int ), Class& object)
{
    // just forward to the generic one
    registerCallback([=](int x){ (object.*method)(x); });

    // or bind it
    registerCallback(std::bind(method, &object, std::placeholders::_1));
}
```